# differentiable function; derivate

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

A P-Function is a Differentiable function $f$: $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ with a continuous derivative $f'$ on $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x+f'(x)) = f(x)$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$.

Prove that a P-function whose derivative has as least two distinct zeros is constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume otherwise, that $f$ fulfills the condition but isn't constant. Then $f$ is continuous and there exist $x_0$ and $x_1$ (without loss of generality let $x_1 > x_0$ )such that $f(x_0) \neq f(x_1)$ and 
$$ \forall_{y \in (f(x_0), f(x_1))} \exists_{x\in (x_0, x_1)} f(x) = y $$

Let $x_0$ and $x_1$ be the zeroes of $f'(x)$. We can also choose them in such manner that there don't exist other zeroes of $f'(x)$ in $(x_0, x_1)$. Why? - because otherwise the set of zeroes of the derivative is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, and it must be Pompeiu derivative, which is discontinuous everywhere where it isn't equal to $0$. But the derivative is continuous everywhere, so it must be equal to $0$ everywhere, so $f(x)$ must be constant.

From continuity of $f'(x)$ we know that there exist $x_2 \in (x_0, x_1)$ such that $f'(x)$ is injective on $[x_0, x_2]$ and $f'(x)$ achieves in that range all values from $[f'(x_0), f'(x_2)]$ (Here I assume that $f'(x)$ is positive on $(x_0, x_2)$. The proof for decreasing $f'(x)$ is analogous). We may then choose such $x_3 \in [x_0, x_2]$ such that $x_3+f'(x_3) \in [x_0, x_2]$ (again from continuity). However $f(x_3) = f(x_3+f'(x_3))$ and $f$ is continuous so there must exist $x_4$ in $(x_3, x_3+f'(x_3))$ such that $f'(x_4) = 0$. But $x_4$ lies in $(x_0, x_1)$ and we assumed that there are no  zeroes of the derivative in that range, which leads to the contradiction, qed.

Comment: I didn't understand how you assumed that f '(x) has zeros

Comment: A simple doubt. Excellent resolution!

Comment: My contradictory assumption is that $f(x)$ is non-constant, fulfills the condition and is continuous and that $f'(x)$ is continuous and has at least two zeroes. Then by showing contradiction I prove that $f$ must be constant